# How does one solve $y^y-x^x=x$ for $x$ as a function of $y$?

Tags: functions, exponentiation

In order to find the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1115072/8530) question I started thinking that as a first step to obtain the first and second column, one would have to solve the equation:

$$y^y-x^x=x$$

for $x$ as a function of $y$.

Can it be done?

Comment: Are you looking for a closed form?

Comment: Not necessarily. A list of numerical values that satisfy the equation would also do.

Comment: Would it help to use the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_2) to solve for $y$ as a function of $x$? This gives $y=\frac{\ln(x^x+x)}{\mathrm{W}(\ln(x^x+x))}$.

Comment: It helps a little bit yes. Later on I am also interested in the equation $y^{y^y}-x^{x^x}=x$. The direction of the recursion in the linked question is towards $x$ though.

Comment: The solution$($s$)$ to $y^{y^y}=a$ cannot be expressed even ij terms of Lambert's *W* function.

Comment: The link in the question is to a deleted post. Please fix this.